# Proving that equality of Schwarz Inequality implies linear depedence for Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory

Precisely, I want to show that

$$|E(XY)|^2 = E(X^2)E(Y^2) \implies X,Y \text { linear dependent }.$$

So The former holds when the discriminant of

$$h(x) = E[(x|X| + |Y|)^2]$$ is zero, i.e. when it only has one solution. Further I can solve for that solution and

$x = \frac{-E(|XY|)}{E(X^2)}.$

Plugging in we get

$$E[(\frac{-E(|XY|)}{E(X^2)} \cdot |X| + |Y|)^2] = 0.$$ But I have no idea what to do with this. Anything helps!

Answer (score 1):

No, you have it backwards. That equation implies they are **linearly dependent**, not linearly independent.

By the way, you should not have absolute values around the $X$ and $Y$.

Hint: if the square of some quantity has expected value $0$, what does that say about the quantity?

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo. I'm not quite sure why the absolute values  around $X,Y$ are incorrect. I copied $h(x)$ verbatim from Ashe's Basic Probability text. So then the quantity itself is equal to zero, then can I expand out somehow?

Comment: $h X + Y = 0$ says that $X$ and $Y$ are linearly dependent. $h |X| + |Y| = 0$ would say $|X|$ and $|Y|$ are linearly dependent, which is not what you want.